# JSP Catching Event from RadionButton

Tags: spring, jsp

I am looking for something like onchange listener for radiobutton in JSP. I am using  like this example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springmvc/springmvc_radiobutton.htm
Anyone know how to catch the event of the radiobutton on the controller ??

Answer (score 0):

There does not exist a default way to do this in Spring. Why exactly do you want to do this?

You basically would use an AJAX call to send the data of the selected button to the Rest Controller.  Something similar to this pseudo-code.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#your-buttons").change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = formname.your-buttons.value;

        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "your/api/url",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                display(data);
            },
            error : function(e) {
                display(e);
            }
        });

      });
    });
```

Then on your Rest Controller you would simply have to handle it like any other event.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/your/api/url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String whatever(.....) {
    // ...
}
```